# Can we grant SELECT privilege for view in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle10g, privileges, sql-grant

I'm using Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4.0 version.

I need to grant SELECT privilege for a **view** present in *"DRAGON"* Schema to *"BALLZ"* Schema.

Is it possible ?

If possible then please let me know the query.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as

```
GRANT SELECT ON <your_view> TO BALLZ;
```

You have to execute the above from DRAGON schema.

If you would like to execute as SYSDBA, try as

```
GRANT SELECT ON DRAGON.<your_view> TO BALLZ;
```

Comment: Is there any other way to execute it from SYSDBA user ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge !

Comment: @ARGtheYoYoBro Glad that this has helped.